# How do I finish the edge of a shower surround next to dry wall corner wall?

Tags: drywall, shower

I have a new shower surround with UMaxx tile and the edge of it leaves a gap to dry wall on corner. I’ve heard many different opinions on how to finish this from metal corner bead, plastic tear away corner bead, L Trim wood, and more dry wall with corner bead. I just want a simple and durable solution. Thank you. [image]

Comment: Are you repainting?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and most durable solution is to cut the drywall above the shower, near the corner to the ceiling.

That leaves the open corner of drywall and the shower edge with the drywall above.

Purchase a PVC or composite trim that will not be effected by moisture.
(there is your durable)

Get something that is thick enough to cover each edge of the drywall. Maybe 1x2 or 1x3 ?  (The dimensions are not perfectly evident in your pic.)

Cut the trim and fit it from floor to ceiling. Attach with some adhesive caulk and a few finishing nails.   Caulk the seams where the drywall meets the trim.

No corned beads. No drywall mud, nothing special.  (There is your simple)

Paint if desired... Done